# Advanced carousel is invisible and the dropdown button is gone

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, carousel

WP/Plug-in/Theme updates broke our site's "select a campus" button.  It is a button that drops down a previously hidden carousel of campus images that scroll horizontally. 
Clicking one redirects you. It is in the custom js of the theme, so that it is a sitewide header.  The carousel is called "Advanced Carousel" built through the "Ultimate Addons for WPBakery"

I'm sorry, I have next to no web experience, and I was handed this website after someone else broke it.  I am trying my best to learn as much as possible.  Everything else now works but this part.

This is for a newly updated WP site, which hadn't been updated in years.  When WP itself was updated, it broke all the sites and that's as far as the previous people got.  I updated the plug-ins and themes and that fixed most the issues other than this carousel.

Here is the custom JS that is a part of the theme (should apply to every site's header I beleive).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.select-campus a').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('#select-a-campus').toggleClass('active');                  
        });
});
(function (n) { n.fn.sticky = function (t) { var i = n.extend({}, { 
topSpacing: 0, bottomSpacing: 0, debug: !1 }, t), r = function (t, r, u) { var o = u.offset(), e = n(window).scrollTop(), f = n(document).outerHeight() - i.bottomSpacing - i.topSpacing - t.outerHeight(); f <= 0 || t.height() <= 0 || (e > o.top - i.topSpacing && e < f ? (t.css("position") != "fixed" && (t.trigger("sticky-start"), t.css({ position: "fixed", top: i.topSpacing })), t.trigger("sticky-bottom-unreached")) : e > o.top - i.topSpacing && e >= f ? t.css("position") == "fixed" ? (t.trigger("sticky-bottom-reached"), t.css({ position: "absolute", top: f - r.offset().top + i.topSpacing + "px" })) : t.css("position") == "absolute" ? t.css({ top: f - r.offset().top + i.topSpacing + "px" }) : f > o.top && t.css({ position: "absolute", top: f - r.offset().top + i.topSpacing + "px" }) : ((t.css("position") == "fixed" || t.css("position") == "absolute") && t.trigger("sticky-end"), t.css({ position: "", top: "" }))) }; return this.each(function () { var t = n(this), u = t.offsetParent(), i; t.width(t.width()); i = n("<div class='sticky-holder' style='visibility: hidden;height:0;display:block'><\/div>").insertBefore(t); r(t, u, i); n(window).scroll(function () { r(t, u, i) }) }) } })(jQuery);

 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
      $('.vc_custom_1489943500023, .vc_custom_1489936456809').sticky( {topSpacing: 20,bottomSpacing:$("#page-section-40").outerHeight(true)} );
    });

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please tell me if I can do anything else to help understanding.  Sorry I don't know more.  Any help is appreciated.

No error messages, however if you hover the mouse within a handful of pixels below the header, you are able to click some of the hidden campuses.

EDIT 1:  here is the link to the html https://github.com/dtnieboer/sh-html/releases/tag/1.0

EDIT 2: Hey guys!  An update- yes this job would be way too hard with my skill level.  Going to get rid of the old code and rebuild a more simple button for now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you add the html of the page?

Comment: Even if 90% of the time nothing breaks on update, upgrading WordPress and specifically updating custom code to match theme and WP changes is not a trivial task, even for experienced web developers. And fixing it can vary greatly from case to case, depending on theme, installed plugins, the quality of your custom code and many other factors. Considering your experience, the best thing you can do is roll-back the changes and ask for professional help. With what you provided your question is not answerable.

Comment: I’ll give it a shot asap Daan Thank you.

Comment: thank you for letting me know how severe this is Andrei, I will take that into account when reporting to my peers.  So much better knowing that this is a hard job.

Comment: Hey guys!  An update- yes this job would be way too hard with my skill level.  Going to get rid of the old code and rebuild a more simple button for now.  Thanks for the help!